# Why are my downvotes being undownvoted?

Tags: support, serial-voting

Yesterday I downvoted few answers to a question. I flagged one of them. Decided that if I downvote the answer the user that posted all those answers (which are basically, the same answer edited to fit the needs of the asker, but instead of editing his first answer he has posted new ones) that will bring his attention to those posts and take some actions. I'm talking about this question:

[Some thing wrong with my sharing script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266963/some-thing-wrong-with-my-sharing-script/28267186#28267186)

However today I can see in my reputation log that those downvotes are removed. Can I know why were they removed or it's some sort of an algorithm that has detected that I have downvoted several answers of the same user in short period?

Comment: `it's some sort of an algorithm that has detected that I have downvoted several answers of the same user in short period?` yup, that exists - it's been known to kick in at 3 votes or so, although the exact workings of the algorithm are secret. How many downvotes did you cast on that user's contributions in total?

Comment: @Pekka웃 3 (2 from the question I mentioned in this post and 1 that was link only answer that I did not find helpful) .

Comment: Hmm, strange. I've cast a lot more downvotes in situations like that and to my knowledge they've never been removed (but then I don't pay a lot of attention to the page that would tell if they had). Either way, it was the mass downvote mechanism, it's an important tool to have even though it's unfortunate the votes were removed in this case.

Comment: You're not allowed to vote on users, only on posts. Of course that's a bit tricky when one user adds lots of answers to a single post. In that case you'd have been best flagging for moderator attention with a custom flag, explaining that the user is adding multiple answers rather than editing his existing answer.

Comment: I think the meta effect will take care of those answers.

Comment: @Renan yeah, everything looks fine now. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I know why were they removed or it's some sort of an algorithm
>   that has detected that I have downvoted several answers of the same
>   user in short period?

Yeah. SE has that, and it runs every night. The exact details of how it works are unknown, to prevent people from gaming it, but generally speaking, if the system thinks you're serially targeting a user, it will reverse it. If that happens frequently, a moderator will talk to you eventually.

For now, I don't think you'll hear from it again, as it was a one time thing. Just remember, we vote on the content here, not the users.

Comment: I say as long as you're voting on bad quality content and not to harm a specific person, vote away. As long as you stick to that, if ever a moderator contacts you over it, you have nothing to fear.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - That is true in some sense. However, doesn't that encourage going through that specific user's posts and voting on them? It is a slippery slope to encourage finding posts to vote on based on user.